# Некорректное отображение калькулятора на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сделала калькулятор на сайте WordPress, но почему-то калькулятор корректно отображается только когда находишься в админ панели сайта, для неавторизованных пользователей калькулятор некорректно отображается, там просто вместо цифр сам код виден.
Вот сам код калькулятора:

```
<section class="content-section">
            <div class="calc" id="calc">
                <div class="calc-payment" v-bind:class="{ screen: isActive }">
                                    <h2 class="title_calc">Калькулятор лизинга</h2>
                                        <div class="calc-field">
                        <div class="request-field">
                            <label class="range-label">Стоимость</label>
                            <input class="range-field" v-model.number="price" />
                        </div>
                        <vue-slider v-model.number="price" :min="200000" :max="20000000" :interval="1000" :tooltip-formatter="val => formatPrice(val) + ' ₽'"></vue-slider>
                        <span class="calc-field-limited">от 200 000 до 20 000 000 ₽</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calc-field">
                        <div class="request-field-flex">
                            <div class="request-field request-field__left" v-if="advanceType == '%'">
                                <label class="range-label">Аванс</label>
                                <input class="range-field" type="text" v-model="advancePercent" />
                                <vue-slider v-model.number="advancePercent" :min="5" :max="49" :tooltip-formatter="'{value} %'"></vue-slider>
                                <span class="calc-field-limited">от 5 до 49 %</span>
                            </div>
                            <div  class="request-field request-field__left" v-if="advanceType == '₽'">
                                <label class="range-label">Аванс</label>
                                <input class="range-field" type="text" v-model="advanceRub" />
                                <vue-slider v-model.number="advanceRub" :min="price*0.05" :max="price*0.49" :tooltip-formatter="val => formatPrice(val) + ' ₽'"></vue-slider>
                                <span class="calc-field-limited">от {{formatPrice(price*0.05)}} до {{formatPrice(price*0.49)}} ₽</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="request-field__right">
                                <v-select v-model="advanceType" :options="['₽','%']" :clearable="false" :searchable="false"></v-select>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div  id="srok" class="calc-field">
                        <div class="request-field">
                            <label class="range-label">Срок</label>
                            <input  class="range-field" v-model="term" />
                        </div>
                        <vue-slider v-model="term" :min="12" :max="60" :tooltip-formatter="'{value} мес.'"></vue-slider>
                        <span class="calc-field-limited">от 12 до 60 мес.</span>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                

                
                <div class="calc-result" v-bind:class="{ screen: !isActive }">
                    <div class="calc-result__mobile">
                        <div class="calc-result__mobile_item">
                        
                    </div>
                        <div class="calc-result__mobile_item">
                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="calc-result__mobile_item">
                        
        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="calc-data-wrap">
                        <div class="calc-data">
                            <div class="calc-data__item">
                                <div class="calc__dt">Платёж в месяц</div>
                                <div class="calc__dd">{{formatPrice(payment)}} ₽</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="calc-data__item">
                                <div class="calc__dt">Сумма договора лизинга</div>
                                <div class="calc__dd">{{formatPrice(agreementAmount)}} ₽</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="calc-data__item">
                                <div class="calc__dt">Годовое удорожание</div>
                                <div class="calc__dd">{{yearIncrase}} %</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="calc-benefit">
                            <div class="calc-subhead">Выгода по налогам</div>
                            <div class="calc-data__item">
                                <div class="calc__dt">Сумма НДС к зачёту</div>
                                <div class="calc__dd">{{formatPrice(creditedVAT)}} ₽</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="calc-data__item">
                                <div class="calc__dt">Экономия по налогу на прибыль</div>
                                <div class="calc__dd">{{formatPrice(taxSavings)}} ₽</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="calc-data__item">
                                <div class="calc__dt">Общие затраты на приобретение</div>
                                <div class="calc__dd">{{formatPrice(acquisitionCost)}} ₽</div>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="calc-dis">
                                </div>
                        
                        <a href="https://leasingber.ru/app/"  class="btn btn-active">Заявка на лизинг</a>
                        
                        <div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
                            <div class="b-popup-content">
                                
                                <div class="b-request-field">
                                    
                                </div>
                        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            </section>
            
            
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#calc',
  data: {
    price: 1000000,
    term: 60,
    branch: [],
    rate: 0.224,
    advancePercent: 10,
    advanceRub: 55000,
    advanceType: '%',
    oniPercent: 3,
    isActive: true
  },
  created: function () {
    if(4227)
        this.switchRate(4227);
  },
  methods: {
    formatPrice: function(value) {
        return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ")
        },          
    switchRate: function(val){
        switch(val){
                case 1934:
                    this.rate = 0.175;
                    break;
                case 1933:
                    this.rate = 0.185;
                    break;
                case 4741:
                    this.rate = 0.195;
                    break;
                case 1942:
                    this.rate = 0.195;
                    break;
                default:
                    this.rate = 0.224;
                    break;
            }
    }
    },
  components: {
      VueSlider: window['vue-slider-component']
    },
      watch: {
        advanceType: function (val) {
          if(val == '%')
              this.advancePercent = Math.ceil(this.advanceRub/this.price*100);
          if(val == '₽')
              this.advanceRub = Math.ceil(this.price*this.advancePercent/100);
        },
        isActive: function() {
            if(this.advanceType == '%')
                this.advanceRub = Math.ceil(this.price*this.advancePercent/100);
        },
        price: function (val) {
            if (val*0.05>this.advanceRub)
                this.advanceRub = Math.ceil(val*0.05);
            if (val*0.49<this.advanceRub)
                this.advanceRub = Math.ceil(val*0.49);
        },
        branch: function (val) {
            this.switchRate(val.code)
        }
      },
        computed:{              
            payment: function(){
                if(this.advanceType == '₽')
                    this.advancePercent = Math.ceil(this.advanceRub/this.price*100);
                
                return Math.round(this.price * ((100 - this.advancePercent) / 100 * Math.pow(1 + this.rate / 12, this.term) - this.oniPercent/100) / (Math.pow(1 + this.rate / 12, this.term) - 1) * this.rate / 12);
            },
            agreementAmount: function(){
                return this.price*this.advancePercent/100 + this.payment * this.term;
            },
            creditedVAT: function() {
                return Math.round((this.agreementAmount + this.price*this.oniPercent/100) / (1 + 0.2) * 0.2);
            }
            ,
            taxSavings: function() {
                return Math.round((this.agreementAmount + this.price*this.oniPercent/100) / (1 + 0.2) * 0.2);
            },
            acquisitionCost: function(){
                return Math.round((this.agreementAmount + this.price*this.oniPercent/100) - (this.creditedVAT + this.taxSavings));
            },
            yearIncrase: function(){
                return (((this.agreementAmount-this.price)*100/this.price)/(this.term/12)).toFixed(2);
            }
        },
})
```

На скрине показано как калькулятор отображается для незарегистрированных пользователей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Калькулятор должен быть обернут в `<div id="calc">...<код калькулятора>...</div> `, подгружается ли скрипт `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>` , есть ошибки в консоли браузера или вкладке network ?